# bypassing HSTS error gives 'file not found'

Tags: symfony, vagrant, hsts

I booted my local vagrant folder today and my symfony project gave a 'hsts error', you can bypass this by typing badidea. After I typed badidea it directs me to a page that says 'file not found', any ideas on how I can get my local symfony project back up and running?

PS: I also tried adding the domain in my chrome://net-internals/#hsts query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using a *.dev domain for your local project?

*.dev belongs to Google and they enforce HSTS now through preloading within Chrome. (Probably Firefox and other broswers will do this too soon if not already since they use the HSTS preload list from google)

I encountered the same error this week after the last Chrome update.

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Try switching your local project domain to *.test or anything else or use a proper SSL Setup with a self-signed certificate and add it to the trust store.

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks for the explanation. I guess ill change the .dev to something else and go from there, or make a SSL setup. Kinda harsh from google to just buy the .dev gTLD :(

Comment: I have a related issue, do you an idea about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47484073/8016060

Comment: @Tokeeen.com an idea maybe: HSTS has a flag that tells wether to include subdomains or not. Probably set to true in your prod config. Don't know how to set it otherwise though. But if you find out how you probably would need to change the config on production. Depending on the lifetime of the old HSTS settings delete the old ones in your browser (under chrome://net-internals/#hsts). It sounds somewhat plausible but i'm just guessing :)

Comment: Be sure to pick one of these four TLDs to prevent the same problem from ever occurring again: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#page-2